# Deleting an entity with reference to self

Tags: nhibernate

I have a class for messages in a message thread. Each message has a reference to the root message of the thread:

```
<class name="Message">
  ...
  <many-to-one name="Root" not-null="true"/>
</class>

<joined-subclass name="Comment" extends="Message">
  ...
</joined-subclass>
```

Now I want to delete a comment. This works fine for all but the root comments. Deleting a root comment, where the Root property points to the message itself, yields the following exception:

```
NHibernate.PropertyValueException : not-null property references a null or transient value 
at NHibernate.Engine.Nullability.CheckNullability(Object[] values, IEntityPersister persister, Boolean isUpdate)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultDeleteEventListener.DeleteEntity(IEventSource session, Object entity, EntityEntry entityEntry, Boolean isCascadeDeleteEnabled, IEntityPersister persister, ISet transientEntities)
at NHibernate.Event.Default.DefaultDeleteEventListener.OnDelete(DeleteEvent event, ISet transientEntities)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.FireDelete(DeleteEvent event)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.Delete(Object obj)
```

This error appeared first when I upgraded from NHibernate 3.0 to 3.3. When I remove the `not-null` constraint, I get an SQL exception indicating that the respective column constraint was violated. Now I wonder why NHibernate actually tries to save a to be deleted entity. Does anyone have an idea how to deal with this?

Answer (score 0):

not-null should be set to false, because, at least one of these entries will require it: the first "father".

Comment: In previous versions of NHibernate, it was possible have the root node pointing to itself, and no entry required this property to be null on the domain side. If NHibernate 3.3 requires this internally, I tend to call it broken.

Comment: This is only possible with assigned primary keys or sequences, because, otherwise, you have to first insert a record in order to obtain its id. This is no internal requirement.